What's the official page that has the complete list of the Penn Treebank Tag set?
I was told that the Penn Treebank tag set has a total of 45 tags. I wanted to find these and note what they were. However, I couldn't find a credible source with the complete list where there was agreement or a credible source with the timeline for when the changes (increasing or decreasing the tags) were made. I ran into this when reading about POS-tagging in natural language processing (NLP).

UPenn page from supposedly 2003 based on the URL has less than 45 tags.

Universitat Politècnica de Catalunya source has 39 word tags and 10 punctuation ones.

University of Delaware source lists 36 POS tags plus 12 others for punctuations and special symbols and cites this paper  Building a Large Annotated Corpus of
English: The Penn Treebank, which has the table below.




Never seen the initial claim that the UPenn tagset has 45 tags. What is the source for that claim?

Ah, you get 45 tags when all the tags for quotation marks are collapsed into one tag.I think I have seen tables like that, but don't ask me where. We are using TreeTagger very often and work with that variant of the Penn Treebank tagset.

Well, now you have the answer.

Here are the Penn Treebank Tagging guidelines. I have not actually counted the tags they mention in there, but that seems to be the official document related to how the tagset is used.

On page 6 it enumerates 36 tags, This document says nothing about the punctuation tags present in the Penn treebank tagset.

This is from 1990, while one of my sources is from 2003. Is there something more recent than 2003?

While the standard tagset is the one with 36 tags excluding punctuation, there is a popular extended tagset also termed UPenn Treebank tagset with 48 tags excluding punctuation. It has twelve additional tags giving the two auxiliary verbs to be and to have distinct tags. Note that the semantics of the VB* tags has changed, from generic verb to the auxiliary to be. Content verbs have VV* tags in this tagset.
This extended UPenn tagset is used by TreeTagger and probably other taggers.


8.2 The Penn Treebank Part-of-Speech Tagset
An important tagset for English is the 45-tag Penn Treebank tagset (Marcus et al., 1993), shown in Fig. 8.1, which has been used to label
many corpora. In such labelings, parts of speech are generally
represented by placing the tag after each word, delimited by a
slash:


pdf for paper
[CAVEAT: I was unable to grab the image from that paper, so I got it from another source but I think it has the same information as in the image in the link given for the Stanford paper.]
In a footnote to that paper, we learn this tagset comes from:
Marcus, M. P., Santorini, B., and Marcinkiewicz, M. A.
(1993). Building a large annotated corpus of English: The
Penn treebank. Computational Linguistics, 19(2), 313–
330
And here is the original paper:
Penn Tree tagset by the original authors of the paper above.
[all bolding mine]
